# Concept Question Regarding Short Rate Model

Tags: short-rate

I have a conceptual question that needs help. Does anyone know whether the short rate model generate discount rate or forward rate?

Comment: From a short rate model, you can bond price and then you can compute the forward rate.

Answer (score 2):

Which is the paper/book you are reading? It should be noted there. But basically
in a short-rate model you have

1. a model for the short rate $r_t$
2. you can calculate zero-coupon bond prices from it by $P_T = E[\exp(-\int_{0}^T r_u du)]$
3. from these prices you can calculate the yield-to-maturity $Y_T$
   which fulfills
   $$
   P_T =\exp( - Y_T T)
   $$
   thus $Y_T = - \log(P_T)/T$.

From the yield-to-maturity of a zero bond you get the spot term structure and then by the usual calculations forward rates.

Comment: @Quant2015 if you like the answer and if it helped you then you could accept it by clicking on the respective button ...

Comment: so short rate is basically a forecasted discount rate in the short term?